# Could Not able to position the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
- (void)loadView 
{

       SettingsTitleBar=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self];
        searchBar =[ [UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 40)];
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Type your City Name";
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
    [SettingsTitleBar.navigationBar addSubview:searchBar];  
        self.view = [[UIView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 85, 320, 392)]; 
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 302)                                                         style: UITableViewStyleGrouped]; 
    [tableView setDelegate:self]; 
    [tableView setDataSource:self]; 
        [self.view addSubview:tableView];


}
```

I Have a UITableViewController,
I have utilized the first 44 pixels height for title bar, and then the next 40 pixels of height for search bar(44+40). These are added as navigation controller subviews. then i am adding my self.view at 85 pixel from top, finally tableview has been added as child to the self.view    . But table view has been overlapped with the Searchbar. I dont what is wrong with it. I tried to change various yPositions of tableview and self.view but still nothing happened. 
Can anyone able to help me out from this ?

Note : I dont want to add SearchBar into UITableviewHeader Section.

Answer (score 0):

U can make the view of size 320X436  and add the tabble view and search bar in that view...

Comment: I need to fix searchbar in solid position. If i do so it will be scrolled along with table view.

Comment: TRY USING THIS FRAMES

self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,436);
searchbar.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,44);
tableview.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320,392);

[self.view addSubview searchbar];
[self.view addSubview tableview];

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't add subviews to the `navigationBar`. Add it to the `view`.

As a sidenote: anything you `alloc` (or `retain` or `copy`), you should `release` or `autorelease`

Comment: I need to fix searchbar in solid position. If i do so it will be scrolled along with table view.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this too, initially.  Don't worry about adding the searchBar as a subview.  Simply do this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

The searchBar will be treated like a header.  You'll want to change the CGRect's size to (0,0,320,44), however.